# Is there a way to get and change a public variable without getting the script first?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a button that I made that is able to activate other objects. It is a physical button that, in this case, is activated by touching it with the player GameObject. It uses this script to activate the other objects:

```cs
    public GameObject[] ThingsToActivate = { };

    void Update()
    {
        if (activated)
        {
            foreach (var Object in ThingsToActivate)
            {
                Object.GetComponent<foo>().Active = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This works *pretty* good, but that means that everything that you put into the `ThingsToActivate` array has to have a script named `foo`. I'd like to put this button on the asset store, but I want it to be very easy to use. I'd like to make it so that you can name the script anything you want, as long as it has the `public bool Active` variable.

Is there any simple way to do this, like searching all of the scripts specifically for that variable, or maybe some sort of workaround?

Answer (score 2):

To get all components regardless of type, use `GetComponents<Component>()`.

To check if the component has a property called "Active", use `GetType().GetProperty("Active")`. If it returns a PropertyInfo instance, you can use its `SetValue` method to set it.

```
if (activated)
{
    foreach (GameObject object in ThingsToActivate)
    {
        foreach (Component component in object.GetComponents<Component>())
        {
            var prop = component.GetType().GetProperty("Active");
            if (prop != null) prop.SetValue(component, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, except I changed ```prop``` to ```active```. It didn't work. I put ```Debug.Log(component.GetType());``` and ```Debug.Log(component.GetType().GetProperty("Active");``` right above that, and I found that the script successfully sees every component, including individual scripts. However, when it looks for the ```Active``` property, it returns ```null```, which obviously isn't what we're going for. I tried setting the ```Active``` variable on the other GameObject to ```false```, but that didn't do anything, which means it just can't find the ```Active``` variable.

Comment: Just from messing around with this and seeing the results, as well as the ```Debug.Log```, I feel like we're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Reflection:

```
foreach (var Object in ThingsToActivate)
{
      var prop = Object.GetComponent<foo>().GetType().GetPropery("Active");
      if(prop != null && prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool)
          prop.SetValue(Object.GetComponent<foo>(), true);
}
```

Comment: I suppose this might work, but as far as I can tell, it still requires the script to be named ```foo```, since it is doing ```GetComponent<foo>()```. I mean, I could be wrong, obviously, that's just what it looks like to me.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of button is this? Why is it not possible that everyone who wants to use it inherits from a certain Type?

**I would explicitly NOT use Reflection here!**

I as a user/developer really wouldn't like to use your button asset and then wonder why it also changes a field in some of my own custom components that eventually has a field/property called `Active` ;)

---

I would rather recommend to use a dedicated parent class you have to inherit like e.g.

```
public abstract class YourButtonListener : MonoBehaviour
{
    // I would even use a property here
    // you'll see below why
    public virtual bool Active { get; set;}
}
```

And use this as type and thereby yes, explicitly force your users/developers to explicitly use this as a type

```
public YourButtonListener[] ThingsToActivate;
```

and

```
foreach(var listener in ThingsToActivate)
{
    listener.Active = true;
}
```

Then I as developer know I just have to inherit this type like

```
public class MyListener : YourButtonListener
{
    // Now since I used a virtual property above
    // I can either keep it ad a simple 
    // standard setter and getter 
    // or I can implement an own additional functionality like e.g.
    private bool _active;
    public override bool Active
    {
        get => _active;
        set
        {
            _active = value;

            // Here I can put whatever I like to happen when this is set
            Debug.Log("I just got " + (value ? "activated" : "deactivated"));
        }
    }
}
```

---

Further notes in general:

- Don't use `GetComponent` in `Update` store the references and reuse them.

  By simply making your field of the correct type you don't need `GetComponent` at all in most of the cases. Additionally this forces any referenced GameObject to actually have such a component attached and hinders the developer to (by accident?) reference something else in the Inspector.
- Do not use `Update` for poll checking `bool` values. Rather restructure your code in order to work more event driven e.g. by using a method instead like

  ```
  public void SetActive(bool active)
  {
      foreach(var listener in ThingsToActivate)
      {
          listener.Active = active;
      }
  }
  ```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: After reading your answer and rereading my question, I realize I need to be a lot more specific. The button I'm making is a physical button, where you have to move the player over to it and step on it. I'm sure that that, as opposed to, say a GUI button, probably changes things a bit. Also, having the ```Active``` variable is something that isn't set in stone. It would be pretty easy to have it based on some other variable. Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty new to Unity and C# programming in general, so (1) I'm not exactly sure what a type is, and (2) I've never really used events very much, but I can definitely see how they'd be useful.